# Using TweetTimelineListAdapter method to get the tweets

Tags: android, twitter, twitter-fabric

by making use of TweetTimeListAdapter im able to show the tweets in my application. How do I retrieve the specific details like the message and the timestamp itself?

```
    final UserTimeline userTimeline = new UserTimeline.Builder()
            .screenName("<Your_ScreenName>")
            .build();
    final TweetTimelineListAdapter adapter = new TweetTimelineListAdapter(this, userTimeline);
```

I tried using the adapter class but to no avail.
Thanks!

**EDIT 1:**
Adapter.getCount prints out 0 when there is 2 tweets loaded into the listview.

**EDIT 2**
Adpater.getTweets is not a valid function.

[image]

Comment: DId you got something @Gene

Comment: @Atula i used twitterStream instead, if you want the code i can paste it in pastebin

Comment: yeah sure. I would like to see that

Comment: @Atula http://pastebin.com/H974qXai , I can't remember what I did as it's near a year since i touched this.

Comment: Thank you so much. But I am able to get tweets through   statusesService.userTimeline();

Answer (score 0):

From what I read on the documentation, you would need to get the List of Tweets that you get from the adapter. I think you should be able to get the Tweet list from the UserTimeline object or Adapter.

You would want to pull a `List<Tweet>`, then iterate the `Tweet` for message & timestamp.

Maybe somewhere along this line : (note that I haven't used twitter-fabric at all, so you need to find the correct implementation)

**EDIT**

After reading the documentation, you can do this to get Tweets :

```
final UserTimeline userTimeline = new UserTimeline.Builder()
        .screenName("<Your_ScreenName>")
        .build();
final TweetTimelineListAdapter adapter = new TweetTimelineListAdapter(this, userTimeline);

List<Tweets> tweetsList = adapter.getTweets(); //this will return tweets inside the adapter, if any

for (Tweets tweet : tweetsList) {
    //Do Something with the tweet

    //if you want to get the timestamp : 
    String timestamp = tweet.createdAt;

    //if you want to get the message content : 
    String messageContent = tweet.text;
}
```

Here's the [Tweet Model documentation](http://docs.fabric.io/javadocs/twitter-core/1.4.0/com/twitter/sdk/android/core/models/Tweet.html), you should be able to get anything there. Good luck

Comment: Hi bang, there is no getTweets method in userTimeline.getTweets().

Comment: Can you find any similar method to get list of tweets? there should be one there.

Comment: The only methods i found was for REST apis.

Comment: http://docs.fabric.io/javadocs/tweetui/1.2.0/com/twitter/sdk/android/tweetui/TweetViewAdapter.html TweetViewAdapter able to get tweets. how do i go around doing it?

Comment: anyway, just get the Tweet objects from the TweetViewAdapter, then you can get the message and timestamp :)

Comment: TweetViewAdapter a1 = new TweetViewAdapter(this);
        System.out.println("DSD:" + a1.getCount());
It is printing nth as i think it did not make any connection to twitter svr.

Comment: Morning ried, see the above edit screenshot. It is not a valid method. Thks!

Comment: Update your fabric library, use the latest one, 1.4.0 or something if I recalled correctly